# How do all the flashbang-like grenades work?

Tags: planetside-2

There are three flashbang-like grenades in Planetside 2: heavy assault troopers get a *concussion grenade*, light assaults use *flash grenades*, and infiltrators can carry *EMP grenades*.

They all have a similar purpose: disable hostiles, making it easier for your squad to sweep the area and making return fire more difficult.

But they seem to have different effects. What other differences are there? What is their effect radius? Is there effect reduced at further range? Is there some indication that a target is affected by such a grenade? Basically, I'd like a fairly in-depth description of all these devices.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking as you answered your own question in the question itself.

Comment: @JLaBella I believe that is OP's [research](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and not an answer to their own question.

Comment: @JLaBella I only have a partial answer. It's full for the EMP, I suppose (unless there is some factor not present in VR), but flash and concussion grenades have no data on effect radius and duration, and I'm not entirely certain what I have is entirely correct, either. If I manage to test them in a controlled environment (tossing grenades at my own feet at the warpgate, for **SCIENCE**), I'll probably be able to fill those blanks in myself, but it's going to take me a while. I only have the concussion grenade unlocked. But if I complete this research, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

After testing these grenades in a (relatively) controlled environment, I have acquired these fairly accurate details. I even used a stopwatch.

Flash grenade:

- 4-second fuze.
- whites out the screen, including the HUD. Takes 8 seconds (at point blank) to dissipate completely, but vision starts returning at 5 or so.
- works regardless of facing. Turning away from the flash won't help.
- effect diminishes with distance. At 5 metres the screen isn't completely whited out. Barely any effect at 10.

Concussion grenade:

- direct action (impact) fuze.
- impairs vision within 10 metres of blast.
- slows down turning at 15 metres.
- duration is approximately 6 seconds.
- effect seems to be somewhat randomised or vary with distance.

EMP grenade:

- direct action (impact) fuze.
- effect radius is 10 metres.
- disables personal shields.
- disables HUD for approximately 8 seconds. This includes the crosshair, but iron sights and scopes can still be used.
- slightly impairs vision.
- effect does not vary with distance.

Comment: Question! Will an EMP:
a) Disable cloaking on a cloaked infiltrator?
b) Disable overshields on a heavy assault?
c) Disable area heal on a medic?
d) Disable jetpack on a overflying light assault?

Comment: @Turtleweezard good questions! Since I don't play as an infiltrator, I'm going to have to unlock the EMP just so I could test it. But once I do, I'll update.

Comment: Preliminary VR testing indicates that the EMP is blocked by the heavy's shield, knocks cloakers out of their invisibility, and does nothing to medics' and flyers' abilities. These results are weak, however, since it was used in the VR, on a friend. The grenade worked very inconsistent there.

Comment: Concussions no longer have a direct impact fuse. They explode after a standard timer. EMP grenades also destroy all infantry deployables in the blast (excluding engineer turrets and ammo)